# removing part of a string (up to but not including) in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to strip off part of a string.

e.g. Strip:-

```
a = xyz-abc
```

to leave:-

```
a = -abc
```

I would usually use lstrip e.g.

```
a.lstrip('xyz')
```

but in this case I don't know what xyz is going to be, so I need a way to just strip everything to the left of '-'.

Is it possible to set that option with lstrip or do I have to go about it a different way?

Thanks.

Comment: Write us some unit tests to understand how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = 'xyz-abc'
>>> a.find('-')  # return the index of the first instance of '-'
3
>>> a[a.find('-'):]   # return the string of everything past that index
'-abc'
```

You could use a conjunction of `.find` and splicing.

Answer (score 6):

If there's only one `-` character, this will work:

```
'xyz-abc'.split('-')[1]
```

If you want the `'-'` in there, you have to reattach it:

```
>>> '-' + 'xyz-abc'.split('-')[1]
'-abc'
```

There's also count parameter that allows you to split only at the first `-` character.

```
>>> '-' + 'xyz-ab-c'.split('-', 1)[1]
'-ab-c'
```

`partition` is also potentially useful:

```
>>> 'xyz-abc'.partition('-')
('xyz', '-', 'abc')
```

It splits at the first occurrence of the separator:

```
>>> ''.join('xyz-ab-c'.partition('-')[1:])
'-ab-c'
```

Comment: This gets rid of the `'-'`, so you'll have to do a `'-' + ...`. Also, do `.split('-', 1)` to force it to only split once.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no guarantee that the text to the left of `-` doesn't contain dashes of its own, the reversed version of `find` called `rfind` is even more useful:

```
>>> s = "xyv-er-hdgcfh-abc"
>>> print s[s.rfind("-"):]
-abc
```